# Read data attributes of MenuItem in TextField's onChange event handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a `TextField` in `select` mode that contains `MenuItem`s. I want to pass on additional information while handing `TextField`'s `onChange` event.

I thought that I might include those as data attributes on `MenuItem`s, but so far, I found no way of actually doing it.

```
function MyComponent({options}) {
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('');
const changeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  //read option-id and do stuff with it here
  setValue(e.target.value);
};

return (
    <TextField select onChange={changeHandler}> value={value}
      {
        options.map(
          (option) =>
            <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.value} data-option-id={option.id}>
              {option.value}
            </MenuItem>
        )
      }
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

This is a super dumbed-down version of the code I already have. I can't put `option.id` in `MenuItem`'s value, because it needs to be the string from `option.value`. Also, `option.value`s are not unique.

I could write a custom component that does this, but being able to use `TextField` would really simplify things.

`e.target` appears only to contain the value and name of my `TextField`, and I see no other useful information in the event.

Comment: I think I'll might be able to read those data attributes inside of `onClick` event handler for my `MenuItem`s. There are still things to figure out, as I need to keep the `changeHandler` mostly intact, but safely modify state inside `onClick` event handler (actual value state is way more complicated).

Comment: Hi jahu! Have you checked my below answer? Let me know please :)

Comment: Ran into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the id as value, and get the corresponding option from the array you are getting as a prop if you need to, like so:

```js
function MyComponent({ options }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
  const changeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const id = e.target.value;
    const option = options.find((o) => o.id === id);
    setValue(option.value);
  };

  return (
    <TextField select onChange={changeHandler} value={value}>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <StyledMenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
          {option.value}
        </StyledMenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've rubber ducked my problem by asking question on SO. In my case I can't use id as value inside `MenuItem` as it's part of a bigger form where all inputs are string based. The solution was adding an `onClick` handler to `MenuItem` and moving what I originally had in my `changeHandler` there. This results in some code duplication between `changeHandler` and `clickHandler`, but I could use `useCallback` to avoid duplication.